# Python character constants for chat bot

Tags: python, unicode, constants

I'm currently writting a chat bot in python and I would like to be able to type special characters like emoji, etc. my first attempt was just to place the literal character in the code.

```
add_reaction('ðŸ‡¦')
```

Unfortunately not many editors support these characters, so they appear mostly as random gibberish. For readability this isn't very good either.

To solve the gibberish issue I used `chr(charcode:{int})` which also made them more copy paste save.

Then I put all of them to a separate file `special_chars.py` so i could give the characters a name

```
thumbs_up = chr(...)
smiley_face = chr(...)
regional_a_z = [chr(127462+i) for i in range(0,25)]
...
```

However this file started to grow really long really quickly.

So is there a better way to do this?

Something to keep in mind:

- if a long file isn't avoidable could the character codes be moved to a non-python file
- potential list for consecutive characters or character groups ex: thumb-up and down, list of regional indicators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unicodedata module of the standard library already contains names for the special characters:

```
>>> unicodedata.lookup('THUMBS UP SIGN')
'\U0001f44d'
>>> unicodedata.lookup("REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER A")
'\U0001f1e6'
```

You can get the official name of a character by its code:

```
>>> unicodedata.name('\U0001F600')
'GRINNING FACE'
```